# Let $H$ be the cyclic group generated by $x \mapsto x^p$: $F^H = \{ \sigma \in H \mid \sigma(a) = a \ \forall \ a \in F \} = \mathbb F_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a perfect field with $\text {char} \ p > 0$ ($p$ is a prime).

Let $x \mapsto x^p$ denote the Frobenius automorphism and let $H$ be the cyclic group of automorphisms generated by the automorphism above.

How do I see that the fixed field of $H$, $F^H = \{ \sigma \in H \mid \sigma(a) = a \  \forall \  a \in F \} = \mathbb F_p$ ?

I see that each $\sigma$ maps $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$ to the same element modulo $p$ by applying $(1+1)^p = 1^p + 1^p = 1 + 1$. However, why does no other element in $F$ has this property ?

Also the equality with $\mathbb F^p$ is by isomorphism, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the hypothesis that $F$ is perfect. What you defined with
$\{\sigma\in H\mid \sigma(a)=a\ \forall a\in F\}$ is the singleton $\{id\}$, which is a subgroup of the automorphisms. 
What you had in mind is $F^H=\{a\in F\mid\sigma(a)=a\ \forall\sigma\in H\}$. Notice that $a\in F^H$ iff $a^p=a$ (if $a$ is fixed by the Frobenius automorphism, $a$ is fixed by all the cyclic group that it generates). 
Now $a\in F^H$ iff $a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^p-x$, which has exactly $p$ roots counted with multiplicity. Since you already know $p$ distinct roots (the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$), there are no other roots.

Comment: Thank you very much Mizar. I need that $F$ is perfect in order to conclude that the Frobenius endomorphism is an automorphism ? In my textbook, a field $F$ is perfect if it has prime characteristic $p$ and the Frobenius endomorphism is surjetive (it is injective by default).

Comment: The usual definition of perfect field is that all the algebraic extensions are separable.
This is equivalent to the surjectivity of the Frobenius map: if $F$ is perfect the Frobenius must be surjective (otherwise you could easily construct an inseparable irreducible polynomial..). On the other hand, if Frobenius is surjective, there are no inseparable irreducible polynomials, as they would have the form $p(t)=\sum c_k t^{pk}$ (with $c_k\in F$): since each $c_k$ is a $p$-th power, the whole $p(t)$ would be the $p$-th power of some polynomial in $F[t]$, so would not be irreducible, absurd.